# ToggleClass not working Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a link that, If I click on it while is set with `.m`  the class changes to `.n`, But if I click on it again, once It is supossed to have changed, it doesnt show up the alert...what is wrong?

HTML

```
        <div class="m" >[enlace]</div>
```

JQUERY

```
         $(".m").on('click',function(){

          $(this).addClass("n");
           $(this).removeClass("m"); //or toggleClass?

            }); 

        $(".n").on('click',function(){

           Alert("n");

              });
```

It looks like it doesnt recognize the div have a new `.n` class that the alert doesnt show up.

Comment: it should be `alert("n");` not `Alert("n");`

Comment: At the point the Element gets the n class the jquery initialization is already done. You hav to bind exactly one Click handler and decide within this handler what to do. Take a third class to bind the handler. And use m and n only to decide what to do.

Comment: try $('body').on('click', '.m', function(){// your stuff})

Comment: @David, so you mean....`if has class m do this, class n do that` within the new click handler?

Comment: @Joe, see my answer below. That is the code to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can do it this way:

```
$(".clickable").on('click',function(){
    if ($this).hasClass("m")) {
        $(this).addClass("n");
        $(this).removeClass("m"); //or toggleClass?
    } else {
        alert("n");
    }
});
```

Comment: It has totaly sense....Ill test it this way. So my link would need to be ` <div class=" clickable m" >[enlace]</div>` at the beguinning

Comment: Or `$(".m, .n")` to avoid usage of `clickable` class

Comment: Sure that is possible too. As m and n have no meaning at all, i would create a third class and give each class a meaningful Name. I think my solution is much more clear especially because depending on the Initial Page state you don't need to bin both classes.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain you why it does this. But if the event click on ".m" is still listening when '.m' is no more there, you can just use a count like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var count = 0;
        $('.m').on('click', function(){
            if(count == 0){
                $(this).toggleClass('n');
                $(this).toggleClass('m');
                count++;
            }else{
                alert('OK');    
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to attach events on dynamic elements in Jquery like the one below:

```
$(document).on('click', '.m', function() {
        $(this).addClass('n');
        $(this).removeClass('m');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.n', function() {
        alert("n");
        // $(this).addClass('m');
        // $(this).removeClass('n');
    });
```

Jquery will not be able to attach an event on a dynamic element on page load. Since the element with class 'n' will not be available until the element with class 'm' is clicked the selector $('.n') will not return anything. So we attach a click event to the Static 'document' element and indicate the future element i.e., $('.n') inside it to invoke the event.

Comment: `.on` is sufficient to handle dynamic elements.